# Rails, geting up routes & controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Groups Controller, giving URLS like:

```
/project/3
/project/555
```

In a project I want to have tabs like

```
/project/3
/project/3/activityfeed
/project/3/photos
/project/3/settings
```

What's the right way to set this up in the routes and controller file? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using [Nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

```
resources :projects do
  resources :activityfeed
  resources :photos
  resources :settings
end
```